# Parse PFQuery Where Pin Name Not Equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I am adding offline support to my app with Parse and as their `saveEventually` and `deleteEventually` sucks and doesn't work very well, I need to manage this manually. Which is fine by me.

Anyway, I have made it so that I pin objects with a name to be saved to deleted. If I pin an object to be deleted when back online, I still want to hide it from the current results, as it is going to be deleted.

So how can I make my `PFQuery` so that it doesn't fetch results where the pin name is not equal to my `deletePinName` group.

So I want to fetch everything but those pinned to be deleted.

**EDIT:**

I have found a potential way of resolving this, however it doesn't appear to be working for a reason I can't work out.

I simple create another query which gets all objects pinned to be deleted and then make my main query not include those results.

```
PFQuery *mainQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Box"];

PFQuery *subQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Box"];
[subQuery fromPinWithName:@"DeleteTheseObjectsPin"];

[mainQuery whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"objectId" inQuery:subQuery];
```

Make sense? Get objects which don't match objects in this sub query, meaning the ones that I pinned to delete.

So why is it that when I add this `whereKey` constraints to my main query, do I get zero results?

Comment: PFQuery whereKey:notEqualTo:  (http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:notEqualTo:)

Comment: But what would the key be? Does the pin name count as a key of the object? If so what is the key name?

Comment: @JoshKahane The key can be any of the objects attributes even objectID. Alternatively you can just set a Boolean for the pins to be deleted and just query and return all the objects that return false. But to answer your question you would just do `[query whereKey:@"name of pin" notEqualTo:deletePinName]`

Comment: Ok, it would be most convenient to use the pin names. To clarify, if I pinned an object like so: `[object pinWithName:@"deleteThisObject"];` I then query all objects (excluding those with that pin name): `[query whereKey:@"how do I know what this key is to access the pin name?" notEqualTo:@"deleteThisObject"];`

Comment: I've added a new approach to my question, but it still won't work, thoughts on this new idea?

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, I don't think using PFQuery with complicated constraints to filter the pinned object is a good strategy. You just need to do normal PFQuery to get whatever objects you need from Parse, and before you present the returned data to users, you filter them locally with your pin list. For pin objects to be deleted, you filter them out from the PFQuery results; for pin objects to be saved, you add your local copy into the PFQuery results. To make the pin list small, during each app launch, you can fire a background thread to check if any pin object is on Parse, depending on whether it is deleted pin or saved pin, you can keep it or remove it from the pin list based on the Parse query result for it.